# What is the max length of a file name created programmatically?

Tags: android

I am able to create a file in android with about 100 character name through java.

But when I try to create a file from the device they limit me to 50 characters.

**Question**

Is there a limit to a file name? Why does android limit the file name when done manually? should I worry if my file name becomes too long?